# Elastic search and Lucene for Django and MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine

I'm implementing a search engine in my Django project with MongoDB. But I have some confusion about choosing between Lucene and ElasticSearch. As mentioned, I'm using MongoDB for storing data. Anyone, please give me the technical reason for choosing Lucene over ElasticSearch. Which one is better for indexing and analytics as well.

Comment: It depends on your needs obviously. But Elasticsearch is using Lucene behind the hood. So I would guess you should go for Elasticsearch, as it expose a rest API.

Comment: But I need to implement it in my local machine currently. Is it possible to implement this algorithm on my project without using Elastic RESTfull API?